# How does the inductive reversal process of the emission of EM radiation at the receiving antenna work?

Tags: radiation

The emission of EM radiation is based on an induction process in which a periodic electrical voltage creates a magnetic field that is offset by 90° in time and space, also known as the starting near field of the radiation.

If the receiving antenna rod is aligned in the same way as the transmitting antenna, the incoming EM radiation again becomes an oscillating voltage. What is the temporal phase of the magnetic field in relation to the electric field? Of course, the question could also have been asked for a magnetic antenna, where the incoming magnetic field component of the radiation triggers the induction process in the receiving antenna.